# I am trying to unit test Behave files in python. Does anyone know what type the context parameter is that Behave uses?

Tags: python, python-unittest

Tests in Behave are written as (for example)

```
Then parameters will have the following values
| name  | val |
| name1 | 5   |
| name2 | 7   |
```

then in the supporting python the python will have

```
@then("parameters will have the following values")
def check_values(context):
```

I am trying to unittest the python and i don't know how to create a unit test for the check_values function because i am not sure how to create something to pass in as the context parameter. Does anyone know?

Comment: It appears to be documented [here](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#behave.runner.Context).

Comment: thanks - i still am not sure how to unitttest it - but that helps.